# What are the names of all the sci-fi vessels in this artwork?

Tags: spaceship, object-identification, art

[image: Explore the Universe]

This [artwork](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/11/08/new-map-combines-all-your-favorite-video-game-settings-into-one-big-world) is described as featuring "over 120 locations, vessels, and characters." The locations are labeled and there are only a few characters, so that leaves the vessels.

Many I recognize (see below), however, there are many that I don't recognize.

So I ask for you guys' help.

Vessels I noticed and recognized:

- The BttF DeLorean
- The TARDIS
- The space-station from *2001: AS0*
- The Enterprise
- The Second Death Star
- An X-Wing
- The *Close Encounters of a Third Kind* ship
- A Borg ship
- A ship from *The Last Starfighter* (I think)
- Serenity
- The Axiom
- The Millennium Falcon

Comment: I see the 'Planet Express Ship' from Futurama towards the upper right.  I think that is a Viper from Battle Star Galactica low in the middle of pic.

Comment: You are a hard taskmaster, sir...

Comment: How about labeling all the ones you know to get started?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Scroll down the linked page. I refrained from posting a link to the official website as the artwork is for sale and that could be considered advertising.

Comment: [Great A'tuin](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vsbattles/images/b/bb/Paul-kidby-disque-monde-the-great-a-tuin-2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141029164342) isn't really a spaceship! But she, and Discworld, are directly underneath "SE" in the title. To the left is http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/bbzowdhysya2vscll38o.jpg&imgrefurl=http://oppositelock.kinja.com/space-battleship-yamato-1712564376&h=1080&w=1920&tbnid=mvL-bk2LeFhQTM:&tbnh=112&tbnw=199&usg=__5m1jWPWiEBN8S4Jyup96-xM8K2o=&docid=lzqNgOliQruwYM&itg=1

Comment: I think Voltron is on the left.

Comment: Wow, should have read your list first. Half the ones I found are listed here!

Comment: Cannot find a guild highliner from *Dune*, disappointing.

Comment: Have you tried [contacting the artist](http://edison-yan.squarespace.com/contact/)?

Comment: Creation Edge emailed him too.  He's bound to reply to someone.

Comment: The DeLorean? In space?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### This is a community wiki answer, so feel free to add to it or make corrections.

From the [website](http://store.iam8bit.com/collections/postcards-from-space/products/space-worlds-map-by-edison-yan) that is selling the poster:

> Presenting iam8bit's Space Worlds Map, a painstakingly researched poster print that merges together **over 70 popular planetary destinations and *50+ vessels/characters*** into one beautiful, gigantic map. Inspiration comes from a variety of sources - movies, TV shows, books, comics, animation - but despite their origins, everything happily co-exists in this insanely epic artwork by illustrator [Edison Yan](http://edison-yan.squarespace.com/).

Numbers are used to identify large vessels, generally put in the top-left corner of the vessels bounding box.

Letters are used to identify characters and smaller vessels.

1. **[Dark Star](http://minus.com/lZcT5RlVE1Xqa) - *Dark Star*?**
2. [Red Dwarf](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/98/RedDwarfShipOriginal.jpg/220px-RedDwarfShipOriginal.jpg) - *Red Dwarf*
3. The Delorean - *Back to the Future*
4. [Battlestar Galactica](http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/images/8/8bb8/8bb825e1/954331/images-overview-galactica-battlestarwiki.jpg) - *Battlestar Galactica* (2004 series)
5. [Gunstar One](http://thelaststarfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Gunstar_One) - *The Last Starfighter*
6. Comet Observatory - *Mario Galaxy*
7. **[Alien invasion craft](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11113/111135171/3632407-1114418172-id4bd.jpg) - *Independence Day*?  [Visitor Ships](http://themindreels.com/2013/05/07/v-the-original-miniseries-30-years-and-counting/) - *V*?**
8. Sulaco - *Aliens*
9. [Kodan Armada](http://thelaststarfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Kodan_Armada) - *The Last Starfighter*
10. **Gundam  - Possibly [RX-78-2](https://www.google.com/search?q=gundam+rx-78&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIhp-619eIyQIVAageCh3goAuG#tbm=isch&q=gundam+rx-78-2+sword) or [ZGMF-X42S Destiny](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/ZGMF-X42S_Destiny)?**
11. TARDIS - *Doctor Who*
12. U.S.S. Cygnus - *The Black Hole*
13. Event Horizon - *Event Horizon*
14. [United Space Cruiser C-57D](http://swordsandstitchery.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-united-planets-cruiser-c57d-from.htm) - *Forbidden Planet*
15. Galaga - *Galaga*
16. Yamato - *Space Battleship Yamato 2199*
17. Death Star II - *Star Wars Episode VI The Return of the Jedi*
18. Borg Cube - *Star Trek*
19. Jupiter 2 - *Lost in Space*
20. Millennium Falcon - *Star Wars*
21. Planet Express ship, AKA Old Bessie - *Futurama*
22. Deep Space Nine - *Deep Space Nine*
23. Heart of Gold - *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*
24. **?**
25. U.S.S. Enterprise, NCC-1701 - *Star Trek* (original series)
26. [Hermes](http://blog.chron.com/sciguy/2015/09/the-martian-is-a-great-movie-but-it-sends-the-wrong-message-about-our-happy-little-journey-to-mars/) - *The Martian*
27. [Citadel](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel) - *Mass Effect*
28. [Cosmic Ark](http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/913/824574-b_cosmicark_front.jpg) - *Cosmic Ark*
29. Mark I Colonial Viper - *Battlestar Galactica*
30. **?**
31. Alien Mothership - *Close Encounters of the Third Kind*
32. Axiom - *Wall-E*
33. **[Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/98/RestaurantAtTheEndOfTheUniverse.jpg) - *HHGTTG*?**<sup>1</sup>
34. Babylon 5 - *Babylon 5*
35. Thunder Road - *Explorers (1985)*
36. [TCS Lexington](http://www.wcnews.com/wcpedia/TCS_Lexington_(CV-44)) - *Wing Commander*
37. Enemy Base - *Bosconian*
38. Narcissus - *Alien*
39. **?**
40. Serenity - *Firefly*
41. Alpha 7 - *Barbarella*
42. Voltron - *Voltron: Defender of the Universe*
43. SDF-1 Macross - *The Super Dimension Fortress Macross*
44. Moya - *Farscape*

---

- A. Great A'Tuin - *Discworld*
- B. Podracers - *Star Wars Episode I The Phantom Menace*
- C. Podracer, Left & Sebulba's Podracer, Right - *Star Wars Episode I The Phantom Menace*
- D. Robby the Robot - *Forbidden Planet*
- E. Space Invaders - *Space Invaders*
- F. **Whale - ?**<sup>2</sup>
- G. **Star Furies - *Babylon 5*?**
- H. **Another Star Fury - *Babylon 5*?**
- I. Little Dipper School - *The Jetsons*
- J. EVE - *Wall-E*
- K. [Ultraman 80](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_lLsdaCVk3Kk/TIT_eSnIg2I/AAAAAAABz94/uB_T3z6rBA0/s1600/images2.jpg) - *Ultraman 80*
- L. Cthulhu - *Works of H.P. Lovecraft*
- M. **?**
- N. **?**
- O. Starfuries - Babylon 5
- P. **?**
- Q. Starchild - *2001: A Space Odyssey*
- R. Gonzo - *Muppets from Space*
- S. Cosmic Fish - *Muppets from Space*

[image: Labeled image of vessels and characters]

---

<sup>1</sup> *Based on the logo on the restaurant's sign, which matches the cover of the book.*

<sup>2</sup> *Obviously some sort of whale;  it looks like a Humpback or Blue Whale.  This trope is common enough to have it's own page on [T.V. Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceWhale).  Examples include a Sperm Whale in HHGTTG, several species in various Star Trek media, "Star Whales" and similar creatures in Doctor Who, a four dimensional "Möbius Dick" in Futurama, Ruari Robinson's pitch-short for a proposed film called Leviathan, and many more.  We need help figuring out exactly which whale (possibly none of the above mentioned examples) the artist had in mind.*

**Edit:** The artist, Edison Yan, graciously provided me with this list:

[image]

However, their list in incomplete, or unclear. Some items are formatted to say only "Ship", and some don't clearly state the IP they're from.

Of those that are unique enough, **Yvaine** is the only one from the artist's list yet to be included in the master list. Unfortunately, there's still more ships to be named in the master list.

Comment: I believe the second image shows the "Hotel at the End of the Universe" - (the building with the star on top).

Comment: Possible, but unverified (feel free to check and add to the wiki): @300,460 (near TARDIS) -> USS Cygnus from "The Black Hole" (1979), see http://www.standbyformindcontrol.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/black-hole-cygnus-crop.jpg

Comment: Planet in the middle of 1. is Ego the living planet from Marvel comics

Comment: The ship to the right of Discworld (the one the Millenium Falcon is firing at) looks like a Vree saucer (from Babylon 5).

Comment: Critter alert: The blue whale from HGTTG is contemplating above planet G889.

Comment: @MajorStackings I think it's from something else, possibly a game. The whale in the picture is a Blue Whale, and the Whale in Hitchhiker's Guide is a Sperm Whale.

Comment: @CreationEdge Fine. Now I'm contemplating over the blue whale above planet G-889.

Comment: I challenge (4) to be the Battlestar Galactica. It doesn't even begin to look like it. Less so for the listed original series.

Comment: There's definitely some artistic license.

Comment: @WadCheber, sure I can use google image search too and tell you what I had a look around. If you insist - and quite a bucket (pun intended) full of artistic license granted - it's a ship from the reimagined series and not the original (as implied in the text).

Comment: I've deleted my comments that just had suggestions that have been implemented, but I'll include two useful links here from comments I deleted. [This page](http://thenewhorizon.webstarts.com/comparison_chart.html) has a lot of ship size comparisons which might be useful--some of the images are small, but you can right-click any chart to view it in a new window or tab, then use the magnifying glass icon (for most browsers) to enlarge. And [here](http://www.denofgeek.us/movies/14621/top-75-spaceships-in-movies-and-tv) is a list with the author's 75 favorite sci fi ships.

Comment: I notice some of the size comparison charts on the page I linked to aren't big enough even when you zoom in, but [Dirk Loechel's deviant art page](http://dirkloechel.deviantart.com/art/Size-Comparison-Science-Fiction-Spaceships-398790051) has the full-sized charts.

Comment: Above F - it's pretty small, but there's a vaccuum sucking the air from the planet Druidia, a clear nod to Spaceballs even if it doesn't look anything like MegaMaid. 

H - just appears to be another star fury, it's identical to the ones around B5 just below and to the left. 

7 - Looks much more like the V visitors ship than the ID4 one

Comment: If the vehicle to the left of Babylon 5 is most likely a star fury given its proximity, aren't the ones labeled O likely to be star furies too, rather than B wings? The ones to the right and left look the same to me.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Aside from the most glaring omissions - the giant ships we haven't identified - we may have named everything that *has* a name:  "over 70 popular planetary destinations and 50+ vessels/characters".  We ignored the planets, and we have at least 51 names.

Comment: @Wad Cheber - I agree some of the small ships with letters might not have been intended to be anything specific, although I think M and N are likely to be from something given their size and specific shapes. But I was mainly just responding to roryok's comment that H was probably "another star fury, it's identical to the ones around B5 just below and to the left"--if the part about the one below and to the left of B5 is correct, then the ones just to the right (labeled O) are probably star furies too, not B wings.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I have no idea.  Your argument makes sense, but when Richard suggested B-Wings, I saw some similarities.  I actually don't know if the tiny, more or less similar things should have been labeled with numbers/letters at all.  I'll leave it up to you to sort out.  I need to stop looking at this damned picture for a while.  It's starting to burn the negative of the image into my retinas.  :)

Comment: H could possibly be a [B-wing fighter](http://www.vintagestarwarscollectables.co.uk/images/Star%20Wars/Full%20Size/Vehicle,%20playset%20parts/StarWars_B_Wing_Fighter.jpg)

Comment: Given that H is close to the Citidel, could it be the Destiny Ascension?

Comment: M kind of looks like an Imperial Transport, except it's brown

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker The Destiny Ascension should have a much fatter middle, but it is generally a cross shape. Possible with artistic license.

Comment: O has got to be star furies. They're the right shape and right next to Babylon 5. G and H may be as well. 24 could be the modified star furies from later in the series, with the 2-person cockpits.